# How can I handle the result of SELECT 1 by PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

I have this code:

```
$db
->prepare("SELECT 1
           FROM ( SELECT count(*) AS num_week,
                         sum(date_time > unix_timestamp(DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 1  day))) as num_day,
                         sum(date_time > unix_timestamp(DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 1  hour))) as num_hour,
                         sum(date_time > unix_timestamp(DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 1 minute))) as num_1min
                   FROM resend_pass
                  WHERE user_id   = ?  
                    AND date_time > unix_timestamp(DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 1 WEEK))
                ) a 
           WHERE num_week < 12 AND num_day < 6 AND num_hour < 4 AND num_1min < 1;")
->execute(array($id));
```

Well how can I use the result of my query? It returns either `1` when all conditions on `WHERE` clauses are *true* or nothing when something's wrong. Well I need to know how can handle the result of a query which starts with `SELECT 1`?

Comment: Note that if `date_time` is a `DATETIME` then the query should not be using `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()` which takes a datetime as an argument but returns a numeric value in Unix epoch time.  `SELECT 1 AS over_limit FROM ...` will give your output column a name.

Answer (score 0):

You don't even need to know **what** the result is, since you'll only see a `1` anyway, so all you need to do is see if there were results (and how many): [PDOStatement::rowCount](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php)

```
$stmt = $db
->prepare("SELECT 1
           FROM ( SELECT count(*) AS num_week,
                         sum(date_time > unix_timestamp(DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 1  day))) as num_day,
                         sum(date_time > unix_timestamp(DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 1  hour))) as num_hour,
                         sum(date_time > unix_timestamp(DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 1 minute))) as num_1min
                   FROM resend_pass
                  WHERE user_id   = ?  
                    AND date_time > unix_timestamp(DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 1 WEEK))
                ) a 
           WHERE num_week < 12 AND num_day < 6 AND num_day < 4 AND num_1min < 1;");
$stmt->execute(array($id));
if($stmt->rowCount() > 0) {
    // Your code
}
```

Comment: I see, thank you +1 .. Just what about [`columnCount`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.columncount.php)?

Comment: quite contrary, you don't even need to know the number of rows returned if you can simply fetch the row. and of course you should never ever select more rows than you're going to fetch

Comment: @YourCommonSense My purpose of writing that query is checking the number of emails have sent so far for the user. I mean a user just can get 1 email per min and 4 email per hour and so on .. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

When you are selecting just a single row that contains a single value, you have to use fetchColumn().
Note that you cannot use method chaining for SELECT queries with vanila PDO

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT 1 whatever");
$stmt->execute(array($id));
$result = $stmt->fetchColumn();
```

Comment: I see. thank you +1 .. Just this kind of chaining for `SELECT` query would be fine?? `$sth = $db->prepare("query")->execute(); $rows = $sth->fetch();`